'object libz.so from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored' error when running npm install
I added a strip in package.json after that when I tried the "npm install" command the napm install is not working this is error which I facing:-
ERROR: ld.so: object './node_modules/sharp/vendor/lib/libz.so' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored.

I also removed package.lock.json file and tried to install but nothing help .
I also tried to these command but no luck :
    rm -rf node_modules
    rm package-lock.json
    npm update
    npm install

my node version is 10.24.1
npm version 6.14.12
